# How to do a Mysql nested query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables for staff
accounts  = id (PK), stafffname, stafflname
rosters = rosterID (PK), id (FK), week_start, mon, tue, wed etc

I am trying to create a roster summary sorted by dates and then by staff name

My code below is somewhat working.
I can get it to create a separation for the date
but in the nested loop I get extra entries for data that is not there

e.g. I have 4 entries in the rosters table for 3 staff (i.e. 1 staff member has 2 rosters)

```
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/staff/config.php');
            
            
            $sql= "SELECT * FROM rosters GROUP BY week_start ";
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
                if($result->num_rows > 0) 
                {
                 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                 {
                    $accid = $row['id'];
                    echo
                    '<tr><td colspan="9"><center><strong>'.date("d M Y", strtotime($row["week_start"])).'</strong></center></td></tr>';
                    $sql2= "SELECT * FROM accounts JOIN rosters ON rosters.id=accounts.id WHERE rosters.id IS NOT NULL ORDER BY week_start";
                    $result2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);
                    if($result2->num_rows > 0) 
                    {
                      while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc())
                        {

                          $comments = str_replace('+', '<br/>', $row2['comments']);
                          $comments = str_replace('{', '<strong/>', $comments);
                          $comments = str_replace('}', '</strong/>', $comments);
                            if($row['mon_start'] == '00:00:00.000') {
                                $row['mon_start'] = '**:**';
                            }
                            if($row['mon_end'] == '00:00:00.000') {
                                $row['mon_end'] = '**:**';
                            }
                            if($row2['tue_start'] == '00:00:00.000') {
                                $row2['tue_start'] = '**:**';
                            }
                            if($row2['tue_end'] == '00:00:00.000') {
                                $row2['tue_end'] = '**:**';
                            }
                            if($row2['wed_start'] == '00:00:00.000') {
                                $row2['wed_start'] = '**:**';
                            }
                            if($row2['wed_end'] == '00:00:00.000') {
                                $row2['wed_end'] = '**:**';
                            }
                            if($row2['thu_start'] == '00:00:00.000') {
                                $row2['thu_start'] = '**:**';
                            }
                            if($row2['thu_end'] == '00:00:00.000') {
                                $row2['thu_end'] = '**:**';
                            }
                            if($row2['fri_start'] == '00:00:00.000') {
                                $row2['fri_start'] = '**:**';
                            }
                            if($row2['fri_end'] == '00:00:00.000') {
                                $row2['fri_end'] = '**:**';
                            }
                            if($row2['sat_start'] == '00:00:00.000') {
                                $row2['sat_start'] = '**:**';
                            }
                            if($row2['sat_end'] == '00:00:00.000') {
                                $row2['sat_end'] = '**:**';
                            }
                           echo 
                           '
                                <tr class><!-- 2nd row STAFF MEMBER 5-->
                        
                                <td><!--Date Range-->
                                    '.$row2["stafffname"].'
                                </td>
                                <td><!--Date Range-->
                                    '.date("d M Y", strtotime($row["week_start"])).'
                                </td>
                                <td><!--Mon Time-->
                                    '.substr($row2["mon_start"],0,5).' - '.substr($row2["mon_end"],0,5).'
                                </td>
                                <td><!--Tue Time-->
                                    '.substr($row2["tue_start"],0,5).' - '.substr($row2["tue_end"],0,5).'
                                </td>
                                <td><!--Wed Time--> 
                                    '.substr($row2["wed_start"],0,5).' - '.substr($row2["wed_end"],0,5).'
                                </td>
                                <td><!--Thu Time-->
                                    '.substr($row2["thu_start"],0,5).' - '.substr($row2["thu_end"],0,5).'
                                </td>
                                <td><!--Fri Time-->
                                    '.substr($row2["fri_start"],0,5).' - '.substr($row2["fri_end"],0,5).'
                                </td>
                                <td><!--Sat Time-->
                                    '.substr($row2["sat_start"],0,5).' - '.substr($row2["sat_end"],0,5).'
                                </td>
                                <td><!--Comments-->
                                    '.$comments.'
                                </td>
                        
                                </tr>
                            ';    
                      }
                        
                    }
                 }
                }        
            ?>
```

[image]

This picture shows the output. I have highlighted the lines that are actually in the mysql table.

I have tried different types of joins as well as reviewed other examples on SO and other sources, but I cannot get it to sort initially by 'week_start' (in the rosters table) and then by 'stafffname' (in the accounts table) for each valid entry for the week start date.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what is the *question.*  SO isn't a debugging service – please try again.  You need to ask a *specific, targeted* question that the community can quickly understand and answer.  Voting to close.

Comment: If your question is about "the SQL query," as the title implies, the first thing to do is to run that query using some appropriate tool, and see what the answer you get actually is.  Questions about that query, e.g. how `INNER JOIN` works, would be fair game ... but your question should concern exactly that, nothing else.

Comment: Sorry, My question is how to create a nested loop for these tables so that only the actual records show rather than "fake" records.